# NTLM requests in K6

Tags: k6

I am testing the NTLM auth using the release v0.20.0-dev-dccb254. The command line to run the script below looks like:
bin\k6.exe run --vus 3 --duration 30s scripts/getOrder.js

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { check, sleep } from "k6";

export default function() {
  let res = http.get("http://user:password@localhost:8247/orders/2377", {auth: "ntlm"});
  console.log("Status code: " + res.status);
  check(res, {
    "status was 200": (r) => r.status == 200
  });
  sleep(1);  
};
```

The first request succeeds for each VU, but the next ones are all failing. This is the output from K6:

```
duration: 30s, iterations: -
     vus: 3,   max: 3

INFO[0002] Status code: 200                             -
INFO[0002] Status code: 200
INFO[0002] Status code: 200
WARN[0003] Request Failed                                error="Get http://user:password@localhost:8247/orders/2377: Invalid WWW-Authenticate header"
INFO[0003] Status code: 0
WARN[0003] Request Failed                                error="Get http://user:password@localhost:8247/orders/2377: Invalid WWW-Authenticate header"
INFO[0003] Status code: 0
...
```

Comment: I was able to get the next requests to pass with a 200 status code by setting this property to true on the server side. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.unsafeconnectionntlmauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx). The note in the documentation points that using same tcp connection boosts performance, but has a higher risk. I would expect when running k6 with --no-connection-reuse, that a new tcp connection is created and authenticated for each request. The following requests are failing with 401 status code.

Comment: I created another server using a different stack (an Asp NetCore WebApi project with windows authentication) and I get the same problem when using the --no-connection-reuse flag.